# How do I make a python scrip to alphabetize these files. They are little complicated

Tags: python, sorting

I have a file with text like this and would like it to be sorted first numerically and second alphabetically. I would like to make a python script for this but have failed.

Each of the items has a name which begins with a 't'.

This is an example of the file currently:

```
t24KAssetType = 
    (I1    (11)    "boats and boating equipment",
     I2    (12)    "bicycles",
     I3    (13)    "caravans, motorhomes, or trailers",
     I4    (14)    "sporting equipment",
     I5    (15)    "musical instruments",
     I6    (16)    "cameras and photographic equipment",
     I7    (17)    "hobby equipment")

t1Mths10Yrs =
    (I1     "12 months",
     I2     "10 years")  
      
tQAnotherSourceIncome =
        (I1     "Enter up to 5",
         I2     " ")

tDAllExpensesComma  =
        (I1     "after deducting all expenses,",
         I2     "")
         
tKExpenses = 
        (I1     " <underline> after</underline> expenses such as rates and insurance",
         I2     "")
         
tAgain =
        (I1    " again",
         I2    "")
         
tLots_Looking = 
        (I1    "Again, looking",
         I2    "Looking")
         
tApe_Remember = 
        (I1     "<BlueLight22>IF NECESSARY:</BlueLight22> Again", 
        I2      "Remember")
        
tzoo =
        (I1    " and ",
         I2    "")
         
tPool =
        (I1     "Apart from any owned or leased by the business or farm you work for, do",
         I2     "Do")
         
tStuff =  
        (I1  (11)  "jewellery", 
        I2   (12) "art works",
        I3   (13) "antiques",
        I4   (14) "collectibles",
        I5   (15) "other collectibles")
```

And here is an example of how i would like it to look:

```
t1Mths10Yrs =
    (I1     "12 months",
     I2     "10 years")

t24KAssetType = 
    (I1    (11)    "boats and boating equipment",
     I2    (12)    "bicycles",
     I3    (13)    "caravans, motorhomes, or trailers",
     I4    (14)    "sporting equipment",
     I5    (15)    "musical instruments",
     I6    (16)    "cameras and photographic equipment",
     I7    (17)    "hobby equipment")  
      
tAgain =
        (I1    " again",
         I2    "")

tApe_Remember = 
        (I1     "<BlueLight22>IF NECESSARY:</BlueLight22> Again", 
        I2      "Remember")
        

tDAllExpensesComma  =
        (I1     "after deducting all expenses,",
         I2     "")


         
tKExpenses = 
        (I1     " <underline> after</underline> expenses such as rates and insurance",
         I2     "")
                
tLots_Looking = 
        (I1    "Again, looking",
         I2    "Looking")
      
tPool =
        (I1     "Apart from any owned or leased by the business or farm you work for, do",
         I2     "Do")
    
tQAnotherSourceIncome =
        (I1     "Enter up to 5",
         I2     " ")
     
tStuff =  
        (I1  (11)  "jewellery", 
        I2   (12) "art works",
        I3   (13) "antiques",
        I4   (14) "collectibles",
        I5   (15) "other collectibles")

tzoo =
        (I1    " and ",
         I2    "")
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you please format the code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

since your that specific format i have written this code

```
with open("something.txt") as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    a={}
    for i in data:
        if i[0] !=" " and i != "\n":
            b=i[:-1]
            a[b]=[]
        elif i != "\n":
            if i[-1]==")":
                a[b].append(i)
            else:
                a[b].append(i[:-1])


with open("something.txt","w") as file:
    for i in sorted(a.keys()):
        file.write(i+"\n")
        for j in a[i]:
            file.write(j+"\n")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I do need the format to be the same could you please help with that? - As in yes I need the tstuff in different lines

Also the above code is returning an empty file for some reason

Comment: i have edited my answer and it meets your every requirement ... and it does not return an empty file in my case but if it still return an empty file in your case you can try writing second with statement again yourself and in the worst case it still didn't work just tell me and i will look into that matter too

Comment: That is amazing. Than you so much, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
with open('input.txt', 'rt') as file:
    text = []
    block = ''
    for line in file:
        if (line.lstrip().startswith('t')
            and line.rstrip().endswith('=')):  # Start of new item-block
            if block:
                text.append(block)
            block = ''
        block += line
    text.append(block.rstrip() + '\n\n')  # Special treatment of last item-block

with open('output.txt', 'wt') as file:
    file.write(''.join(sorted(text)).rstrip())
```

First the file is chopped into item-blocks, which are collected in a list `text`. Then the list content gets written back sorted (`sorted(text)`) into a new file. The decision about when a new item-block starts is based on the line starting with `'t'` (`line.lstrip().startswith('t')`) and ending with `'='` (`line.rstrip().endswith('=')`). Maybe you can just rely on the first part, the second is a precaution.